# Rails Heroku CSS not appearing in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Everything is working on the local version but not on Heroku

I can see the link to the css file when I view source on the production site

`<link href="/dist/css/example.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

but when I click it I get the default

"The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved."

git status "on branch master nothing to commit working directory clean"

production environment

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.force_ssl = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new


  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Not really sure where to start. It's the only css link that, when clicked, renders the error page. All of the other css links work. any ideas where I am going wrong?

---

update: so I decided to give up for a while and take a break. After coming back I decided to refresh the production env and it works without any changes to the "original" file copy that I had as a backup before changing things in an attempt to fix the issue... so I have no idea what happened, maybe a problem on heroku's end? aliens? quantum mechanic magnetic-reversal?

Comment: please add content of `layouts/application.html.erb`, `application.css`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the asset_path, move your CSS file to app/asssets/stylesheets and add the require in application.scss

If you don't want to use de asset_path then you should move your CSS to the the public folder.

Comment: The css file is in the public folder

it's looking for `/dist/css/example.min.css` and I have that file in `/public/dist/css/example.min.css`

It works with all my other stylesheets, just not this one.

Comment: Is this a rails 5 project?, then try adding config.public_file_server.enabled = true to config/environments/production.rb

Comment: yes, but nothing has worked and I've been trying to almost 2 days now. Tried 20+ solutions I've found on google, nothing works. at this point it would be less effort to start again and just work on a new branch, push changes to a staging environment and test.

Answer (score 0):

Try precompiling your asset pipeline.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git add public/assets
git commit -m "vendor compiled assets"
push to github and then heroku
```